# Laravel developer toolbar like in Symfony Framework

Tags: symfony, laravel-5, toolbar

I have worked with PHP Symfony Framework for some time. This framework provide useful toolbar for developer with many information about application behaviour such as response code or query time.

Have you ever tried implement that tool bar in laravel framework?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer below, instead of updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Laravel there is https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar that has a lot of useful information (queries, views, timings and so on)

Comment: Have you ever used that?

Comment: Is the same logic as in symfony?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symfony too much (used it once a few years ago) - but https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/973269/4270452/740c8c8c-3ccb-11e4-8d9a-5a9e64f19351.png this is idea how it looks like